# angular component inheritance using abstract class

Tags: angular, inheritance, components, abstract

I tried to use a abstract class that is going to be extended by certain components like this:

**_detail.component.ts**

```
export abstract class _DetailComponent {...}
```

**certain detail.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'detail.template.html'
})
export class DetailComponent extends _DetailComponent {...}
```

**detail.template.html**

```
<p>Hello<p>
<otherComp></otherComp>
```

This way I don't have to (and can't) import the abstract class into the module.

Problem: If I use any component with selector inside the **detail.template.html** like the `<otherComp></otherComp>` in the example above, I get a `is not a known element` error (which is not caused by not importing the component in the DetailModule).

How could I solve that?

https://plnkr.co/edit/TbCTldrNMh1WKzrX54n7?p=preview

Comment: Without code we can't help you, so I would say you did not import this `otherComp` into your module. But again, having some code (abstract class, your module, even a StackBlitz ?) would help.

Comment: as I wrote I actually did add it to the module ... code is in work

Comment: And as I wrote, I can't tell you what's wrong without code, so the only explanation would be that. Ok then, I'll wait for it !

Comment: There are as far as I can tell, 3 possible issues for that error. You did not use the right selector: `otherComp` vs `other-comp`. You did not import the component using either the `declarations` array in the `DetailModule`, or importing the module the `otherComp` is part of in the `imports` array of the `DetailModule`. The last option is that you did not add the `otherComp` to the `exports` array of the `NgModule` where it is declared.

Comment: Your plunker is not runnable. Please check this https://plnkr.co/edit/fXKHcHt0nK3FMVxdZv0K?p=preview. What's wrong here?